# Wait for another get to complete in nodejs http

Tags: node.js, express, http, response

I need to send a file via http and later report for any errors. So I setup my basic express http server like this:

```js
const app = express();
app.get('/download', async(req, res) => {
    //sending some big file and remeber all errors that
    //happen during this process
    const errorList = [];
    someWayToPipeTheFile(res, filename)
        .on('error', error => errorList.push(error))
        .on('end', () => reportThatFileWasSent());
    ...
});

app.get('/geterrors', (req, res) => {
    //but how do I wait for the '/download' routin
    //to complete from here?
    const errorList = waitUntilFileIsSent();
    res.send(errorList);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I've figured it out - just add callbacks.

```js
const completed = new Set();
const callbacks = new Map();
const errorList = new Map();
const deleteTimeout = 10 * 60 * 1000; //10 mins

const callCallback = (token, callback) => {
    const errors = errorList.get(token);
    errorList.delete(token);
    callback(errors);
}

const holdErrors = (token) => {
    errorList.set(token, new Set());
    setTimeout(() => errorList.delete(token), deleteTimeout);
}

const setError = (token, error) => {
    if (!errorList.has(token)) {
        errorList.set(token, new Set());
        setTimeout(() => errorList.delete(token), deleteTimeout);
    }
    errorList.get(token).add(error);
}

const onComplition = (token, callback) => {
    if (completed.has(token)) {
        completed.delete(token);
        callCallback(token, callCallback)
    }
    else if (errorList.has(token)) {
        callbacks.set(token, callback);
        setTimeout(() => callbacks.delete(token), deleteTimeout);
    }
    else
        callback(undefined); //incorrect token
}

const releaseErrors = (token) => {
    if (callbacks.has(token)) {
        const callback = callbacks.get(token);
        callbacks.delete(token);
        callCallback(token, callback);
    }
    else {
        completed.add(token);
        setTimeout(() => completed.delete(token), deleteTimeout);
    }
}

//////////////////////////////////////
app.get('/download', (req, res) => {
    ...
    holdErrors(req.query.token);
    someWayToPipeTheFile(res, filename)
        .on('error', error => setError(toke, error))
        .on('end', () => releaseErrors(token));    
})

app.get('/errors', (req, res) => {
    onCompletion(req.query.token, (errors) => res.send(errors));
})
```